# WPF bug? MouseGesture on Single and DoubleClick

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouseevent, double-click

We have implemented a simple InputBinding for mouse click gestures, the code is something like below:

```
<Image.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding OpenDialogCommand}" />
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding OpenDialogCommand}" />
</Image.InputBindings>
```

We expected that WPF is able to recognize Left and LeftDouble gestures and do the respective command. But in practice we found that the Left Click is evaluated first and the second click of the double click is treated as another single click. Since our command is to open a dialog doing a doubleclick will quickly open and close our dialog.

Does anyone meet such thing before?

Thanks.

S.

Comment: Old question, same problem! What I'm experiencing with this dual-input binding on a `TextBlock` is actually the sequence: CLICK CLICK DOUBLECLICK. The events are also processed on Mouse DOWN, [not mouse UP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5048883/1174169). I've looked around a bit and haven't yet found a simple solution for isolating these events.

Comment: Works for TextBlock.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the desired behavior. Note that it is a LeftClick event, which doesn't necessarily mean "LeftSingleClick".  You should check out the [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) utility for investigating exactly which events are getting triggered.

Comment: There is no such gesture as "LeftSingleClick" unfortunately

Comment: @StephenHolt I didn't say there was.  It's a hypothetical name I gave as an example to say "LeftClick doesn't necessary mean it will only fire during  _single_-click events, but not during double-click events".