# How can I trigger an event when the left mouse button gets released in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to trigger an event when the left mouse button gets released. I've tried this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseClick" >
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnBarGroupChangeCommand}"    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ReportsBarGroup, Path=Key}"  />
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and this

```
        <igWPF:OutlookBarGroup.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" 
                          Command="{Binding OnBarGroupChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ReportsBarGroup, Path=Key}"/>
        </igWPF:OutlookBarGroup.InputBindings>
```

These both work. The problem with both cases is that the event fires when the button gets pressed. I need it to fire only when the button gets released. The MouseBinding does not seem to support this. Is there a way to do this with Interaction? What is the best way to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862963/wpf-rightclick-mousebinding-on-release

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try EventTrigger event name "[MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup(v=vs.110).aspx)".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with C# but, as far as I'm aware, MouseBinding doesn't allow the support of mouse-up actions, only mouse-down. Take a look at the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862963/wpf-rightclick-mousebinding-on-release)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your try this:

```
private void btn_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        /////WHAT YOU WANT THE BUTTON TO DO/////
    }
```

If you need to know more about mouse events enter [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This will do either left or right mouse click release. This is not what the OP asked for. It is specifically the Left Mouse button. [Left Mouse Button Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup(v=vs.110).aspx)